# Connecting to Magento Rest API by python

Tags: magento2, rest-api, api, oauth

I'm new to Magento API and actually a python programmer, there are some APIs I should connect to them through Rest and I stick to the first step of authentication with OAuth for getting access tokens and this stuff. Can anyone, please, help me through this in a very clear way.
I've got my consumer key and secret and want to connect and use the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In the magento2 admin panel please create your secrets by following the path:
`Stores > Settings > Configuration > Services > OAuth > Access Token Expiration > Admin Token Lifetime (hours).`

The following code block shows an autorizator class that can be used:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


class Authorizator:
    """
    Authorization Class
    """

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret):
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_key_secret = consumer_key_secret
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.access_token_secret = access_token_secret

    def get_authorization_object(self) -> OAuth1:
        """
        A function that returns the authorization
        :return: An authorization object.
        :rtype: OAuth1
        """

        magento_auth = OAuth1(self.consumer_key,
                              client_secret=self.consumer_key_secret,
                              resource_owner_key=self.access_token,
                              resource_owner_secret=self.access_token_secret)

        return magento_auth
```

To retrieve the magento2_authenticator object just use the following stmt in your code:

```
consumer_key = ""
consumer_key_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

authorizator = Authorizator(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
magento2_auth = authorizator.get_authorization_object()
```

Ideally you can pass the secrets by argparse instead of hardcoding them here.

Use the object then in your request - The following code block describes how to retrieve the current categories.

```
base_url = "https://yourstoredomain.com"
endpoint = r"/rest/all/V1/categories"
params = {"searchCriteria[currentPage]": "0"}
response = requests.get(url=base_url + endpoint,
                        auth=magento2_auth,
                        params=params
                       )

response.raise_for_status()
```

If the application is getting bigger please use the magento2 authorizator object as dependency injection for the relevant functions.